# Accessing the mySQL B-tree from C++

Tags: c++, mysql

Trees are allocated in the Heap.
Hence, there should be a pointer to the root node.

If mySQL takes indexed rows, identifed by the Primary Key and stores them in a B - Tree,
is there a way I can access the B-Tree via a C++ interface?

This is part of a learning process, I'm curious, if I can somehow access the root pointer for the B-Tree of a particular table?

Comment: I think the underlying question should be: Is there a lower-level programming interface to database systems than through textual SQL commands? I've been wondering that for a long time.

Comment: "Trees are allocated in the Heap" - who ever said that?

Comment: Well the index might not all be in memory, or be in a format that is easily readable by an outside program and even it was how would you guess the address of the root node, how would you know when you found it?

Comment: Data structures *are*, period. They're abstract, just like algorithms. You may represent some data on the heap using a data structure. But you can just as well store it on disk. Or on the stack (you lose dynamic allocation, but that's not always needed). Or on friggin' paper (though that makes programmatic manipulation virtually impossible).

Answer (score 2):

The indexes are stored in disk, and are not necessarily resident in memory.  If they were in memory, that would be `mysqld`'s memory, not your application's.   If you want to peruse the indexes yourself, go ahead and open the files--ideally using some of the existing (open-source, of course) MySQL storage engine code.

Comment: And if you care about your data, remember to make backups :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to show a confusion (unless you work on [extending MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/extending-mysql.html), which you didn't say, so I suppose you are not extending MySQL - if you did you would have asked a different question.).

[mysql](http://mysql.com/) is (almost always) used as a server program. Your sysadmin is configuring it, and provides you with the ability to interact with that server (often, thru TCP/IP sockets and using a not-enough documented protocol).

As a naive user or developer, you just send requests to the MySQL server, and you get responses from it. So you don't care about B-tree inside the memory of the mysql process, because your only way of interacting with MySQL is thru the network connection to it with requests and responses.

Or perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Then your question is absolutely not related to MySQL. You seems to want to implement B-trees inside a program, just do it.